# connecting mysql database with oracle mobile adf using JDeveloper 11

Tags: mysql, oracle, mobile, jdeveloper, oracle-adf-mobile

I am using JDeveloper 11, I need to develop an android project that connects to mysql database. So please tell me how to connect mysql database with oracle adf using JDeveloper 11. I am new to oracle mobile adf. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your MySQL DB is on a server.
You'll need to build a layer of web services that expose the data from that DB and then you'll call those services from ADF Mobile to get data.

Here is one approach:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/developing_with_oracle_adf_mobile